# Sy-fy channel movie: scarecrow comes alive and attacks a farmer's son and a school bus, farmer retaliates

Tags: story-identification, movie, sy-fy

There is a movie that was on either one or two years ago. There was a scarecrow that came alive and starting attacking people. First it gets a farmer's son who later went after it for revenge, and a bus full of high-school kids.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly [*Jeepers Creepers 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_2) (2003).

> The story begins three days after the events of the first film. A **farmer**, Jack Taggart, Sr. (Ray Wise) is putting up fence posts while **his son**, Jack Jr. (Luke Edwards) is repairing their car. Billy Taggart (Shaun Fleming) sets up scarecrows in the farm's cornfield. **One of the scarecrows in the field begins to move on its own**. Billy runs to get his brother, but the **"scarecrow" comes to life and pounces on him.** Jack Sr. and Jack Jr chase after Billy and his captor until the **"scarecrow" sprouts its wings and disappears into the sky with Billy.**
>
> A **high school basketball team, their coaches and cheerleaders become stranded on a highway**... **the teens on the bus are toyed with by the Creeper**...